# How to use an SWF to stream video?

Tags: flash, video-streaming

I'm looking to be able to embed an SWF file that will stream videos from a server, but being new to flash, I'm not sure if this is possible, or how to approach it.

It needs to be an SWF because we are embedding the SWF in the OpenSpace Isometric world in order to display video.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to do this. If you need several videos than you can use adobe flash media server or free alternative is red5 server. Both alternative using amf(adobe messaging format). For client side you can use default adobe player or [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) or you can design a new component yourself. To do this you need Adobe flash, it has its own converter for several video types, via drag and drop you can convert your video to compressed .FLV format and stream from server. If you dont need several videos you can just disregard server part as you can stream files via url as well. If you just need simple player for few video I would go with jwplayer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to think about this for a bit, since I'll need to strictly embed just a swf, one time only, and then somehow have it dynamically display the videos in the environment.

Comment: Sorry forget to mention that; adobe flash or jwplayer both of them swf object (shockware flash object). Jwplayer additionally has html5 support.

Comment: so you are saying there's a way I can set the SWF to grab videos from a location on a server? I'm assuming I'd be able to work in some AS3 code for those details?

Comment: if you gonna use jwplayer you dont need any as3 experience, just some javascript which is easy and there is lot tutorial about how to create dynamic playlist. Please check http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12538/supported-player-embed-methods and http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/23/creating-a-javascript-playlist

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm not dealing with a webpage here. I need to strictly use a SWF (no html, css, js) and within it, maybe within the class properties, write some code that will somehow dynamically pull and display movies from a server.

Answer (score 0):

Will the following work for you?

1. Write AS3 code with OpenSpace to dynamically pull & display movies.
2. Compile to a Swf which works without any user interaction, pulling movies as required.
3. Convert that Swf file to a movie which can then be streamed.

Does OpenSpace create a swf file as the final output? If so, I think the above will work.

What kind of total movie length and resolution do you have?

Comment: Hey, yeah that's very close. So the short of how it works, is that Open Space is composed of tiles. Tiles are composed of skins. Skins are SWF files. 

I've successfully created a movie clip as a SWF, imported it as a skin, created a tile, and set it to automatically play in the environment.

I'm looking to do pretty much what you outlined, except that the SWF has to be static, since it will have had to have been made into a skin, which is made in to a tile, which is inserted into the environment. I'm looking to have the SWF act as a container to display movies. They will be short trailers.